# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment error

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, variable-assignment

I'm receiving the following error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

From this code:

```
if (!oPrismaticMaterial = "") {
    for (var i = 0; i < oPrismaticMaterial.length; i++) {
        if (oPrismaticMaterial[i].checked) {
            oPrismaticMaterial[i].checked = true;
            radioChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!radioChecked) {
        bValidated = false;
        sErrorMessage += "Please select grades and metal\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!oPrismaticMaterial == "")`

Comment: ha! I am waiting. It said i had 46 seconds left before i could. :)

Comment: weird, I thought it was...I clicked on the check right below...it was yours when I commented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `!=` instead of `=` in your if statement.

`==` is a comparison for equal to, `!=` is a comparison for not equal to, `=` is for assignment.

Therefore you need to change your if statement from:

`if (!oPrismaticMaterial = "")`

to

`if (oPrismaticMaterial != "")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "=" has to be an "===", it won't work for "==".

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a boolean value in your if statement `if (!oPrismaticMaterial = "")`, I think you want `if (oPrismaticMaterial != "")`.

Comment: holy! thanks, we have 3 people working on our code and we overlook "small" things like that sometimes...